# How do I insert an image into a file using PHP

Tags: php, image, file

I am trying to insert an image into the "images" file inside of my "blog" file. The file for my code is in the "blog" file too, and this is the code.

```
<html>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="image"/>
<input type="submit" name="upload" value="upload"/>
</form>

    <?php


include('blogconnect.php');
include('header.php');
    if(isset($_POST['upload']))
    {

        $imagename = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"] ["name"]);
        $imagedata = mysqli_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"] ["tmp_name"]));
        $imagetype = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"] ["type"]);


$myfile = fopen("images" , "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
$imagename = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"] ["name"]);
$imagedata = mysqli_real_escape_string(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"] ["tmp_name"]));
$imagetype = mysqli_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"] ["type"]);
fwrite($myfile, $imagename, $imagedata, $imagetype );
fclose($myfile);


    if($_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES["image"]["type"] == "image/png") {

    }
    }

?>
</html>
```

What am I doing wrong here when trying to insert. The error that shows says

> die("Unable to open file!")

so it won't even open. If anyone sees any other errors please let me know.

Comment: Insert into the DOM or upload the file?

Comment: Maybe a permission related issue. Does `echo file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];` outputs anything?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save an image to file, you can use `file_put_contents` to do that.

Please try this code :

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="post_image.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="image">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the PHP Code, file name `post_image.php` :

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $title = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $data = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
        $content = file_get_contents($data);

        $img = "/xampp/htdocs/whatever/".$title;
        file_put_contents($img, $content);

        if ($content)
        {
            $img = imagecreatefromstring($content);
            header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
            imagejpeg($img);
        } else {
            echo 'Image not found...!!!';
        }
    }
?>
```

For information `allow_url_fopen` need to set true to use file_put_contents`.
Hope this help you out. :D

Comment: I really believe this will work but is my directory to the file correct:  $img = "This PC/Desktop/New folder(2)/PHP/htdocs/blog/images".$title; The PHP is just xxamp renamed and it is inside a folder called New folder(2). Im not sure I need the PC and Desktop. Images is the folder I want the image in.

Comment: Try using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] to get your path.